# удаление элемента односвязного списка

Tags: c++

Помогите понять в чем ошибка. Удаляет все правильно, но при выводе списка в консоли вылетает ошибка.

```
void del (list **begin, string s) {
list *p = *begin;
if (p == NULL) return;

list *print = *begin;
if (p->st.surname == s)
{
    *begin = p->next;
    delete p;   
    return;
}
if (!(p->next == 0)) {
list *p1 = p->next;
list *p2 = p1->next;
while ((p1 != NULL) || !(p == NULL) || (p2 !=0))
{
        if (p1->st.surname == s)
        {
            if (p1->next != 0) {
                cout << "KEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEK";
                delete p1;
                p = p1;
                p1 = p2;
                p2 = p2->next;
                continue;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "LOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOL";
                delete p1;              
                p = NULL;
                break;

            }
        }
        else {
            cout << "DAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAD";
            p = p1;
            p1 = p2;
            p2 = p2->next;
        }

}
}
else    cout << "MOOOOOOOOOOOOM";
```

}

Comment: не обращайте внимание на cout'ы, я так пытался понять, где ошибка)

Comment: а я пытаюсь понять где нет ошибки...

Comment: это весело, но смысла от вашего комментария никакого)
удаляет у меня все правильно, просто при выводе списка косноль крашится.

Comment: а с чего вы взяли что удаляет все правильно?   Ну  а при выводе крашится, потому что вы не связали  предыдущий обьект  удаленного, со следующим, и вообше у вас в коде  сплошной хаос.

Comment: В чем идея этой странной манеры в одном месте писать `p1 != NULL`, в другом `!(p == NULL)`, в третьем `p2 != 0`??? Три идентичных сравнения, но все три записаны по-разному. Три разных человека писало?

Comment: И в чем состоит задача? Если надо удалить только *первое* вхождение данного элемента, то почему в цикле после удаления делается `continue` и продолжается поиск? Если же надо удалить *все* вхождения, то почему после проверки и удаления первого элемента сразу делается `return`? Вы уж определитесь, что именно вам надо сделать.

Comment: И не надо рассказывать сказки про "правильное удаление". Удаление у вас сделано грубейше НЕ правильно. Чтобы удалить элемент списка, его надо "выцепить" из этого списка, т.е. исправить ссылки в списке. У вас же ничего подобного не делается.

Comment: `pop_back()`, `pop_front()`, `remove()` не слышали?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Давайте я лучше напишу на основе того, что вы написали. Вы же постарайтесь понять как нужно подходить и какие шаги предприняты и на этой основе  самим пытаться увидеть и исправлять свои ошибки.
Исходя из того, что вы написали, я сделал вывод, что у вас есть примерно такое:

```
struct Student {    
    string surname;
    //...
};
struct list {
    Student st;
    list* next;
    list() : st(""), next(0){}
    //...
};
```

Дальше, кажется, вы пишете функцию, в которой вы удаляете из списка студента с такой то фамилией.  Но ваша функция не выдает информацию ( удален ли обьект?). Давайте мы все таки вернем булевский тип, чтобы у нас была информация об успешном удалении (быть информированным всегда хорошо...)

```
bool del (list **begin, string s) {
    if (*begin == 0) return false;
    list* p = *begin;   
    if (p->st.surname == s)
    {
        *begin = p->next;
        delete p;   
        return true;
    }  
    list* p1 = p->next;
    while (p1 && p1->st.surname != s ) { 
        p = p1;         
        p1 = p1->next;  // p1  будет указывать на обьект с  фамилией s 
    }
    // если нет обьект с такой фамилией, то p1 == 0
    if(p1) {              // если найдено то p1 будет указывать на него
        if (p1->next)  {        //  если это не последный элемент
            p->next = p1->next; //так как p указывал на обьект перед p1
        }
        delete p1;
        return true;         
    }
    // если ничего не было возвращено, а значит не найден обьект с такой фамилией 
    return false;  
}
```

Моя цель с помощью кода рассказать все это вам, а не писать лучший код(это для критиков). Теперь вы с этим кодом можете оформить новый вопрос, если много чего непонятно. Или воспользоваться комментарием, чтоб задать свой конкретный вопрос

Comment: `while (p1->st.surname != s && p1) ` лучше все же переставьте местами операнды `&&`

Comment: @avp, конечно я согласен с вами, благодарю